# modbus_read_register - Error connection timed out(no hardware problem)

Tags: timeout, modbus, libmodbus

I am new to Modbus protocol. I want to read data from RS485. I have written C code using Libmodbus library on Linux board but unable to read data getting error connection timed out.

[timeout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJhc4.png)

I connect the LInux board to my PC through a 485-to-USB module, and use the modbus slave software on my PC for modbus testing. To the RS485 port of Linux machine where I run the below C code there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "modbus-rtu.h"  //modbus动态库文件
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint16_t buffer[10];
    modbus_t *ctx = NULL;
 
    int rc;
    int i;
    
    //以串口的方式创建libmobus实例,并设置参数
    ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyS7", 115200, 'N', 8, 1);
    modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode(ctx, 1);
                    
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate libmodbus contex\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    modbus_set_debug(ctx, 1);      //设置1可看到调试信息
    modbus_set_slave(ctx, 1);      //设置slave ID
    
    if (modbus_connect(ctx) == -1) //等待连接设备
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed:%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n----------------\n");
        rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 10, buffer);
        if (rc == -1)                   //读取保持寄存器的值，可读取多个连续输入保持寄存器
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            printf("reg[%d] = %d(0x%x)\n", i, buffer[i], buffer[i]);
        }
        
        usleep(100000);
    }
    modbus_close(ctx);  //关闭modbus连接
    modbus_free(ctx);   //释放modbus资源，使用完libmodbus需要释放掉
 
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked the communication on the modbus slave, the sending and receiving have no problem, as shown in the following picture:

[communication on modbus slave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aofWi.png)

Since I reserved more than one RS485 interface on the Linux board, I connected another RS485 interface to the PC through another 485-to-USB module, and checked the communication on the 485 bus with the serial port debugging assistant.

[communition on serial port debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8lXS.png)

I also wrote a set of custom protocols for RS485 communication between Linux board and raspbery pico board before, and the communication have no problem, so there should be no problem with the hardware.

I have checked the previous post on stackoverflow, and one suggested to start the test from 19200 baud rate, but I adjusted the baud rate of both Linux board and modbus slave to 19200, the error is the same, still timeout error.

Comment: Maybe try connecting your "Linux board" to a PC running a Modbus slave simulator (e.g. [pymodbus](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/blob/dev/examples/server_updating.py) or something like [modrssim2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/modrssim2/)) and see what data, if any, is received. Your code looks OK (except for the baud rate), so more info (what is the "Linux board" model no for the RS485 adapter etc) is needed to try and trace the issue.